# Making Scrapy only crawl descendant links

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following Scrapy code, which I am using to try and scrape only Premier League data from the website in the code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
import time


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "goal3"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/3853/Stages/7794/PlayerStatistics/England-Premier-League-2013-2014"]
    download_delay = 1
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), 
                  follow=True),
             Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_item')
    ]
    def parse_item(self,response):
        self.log('A response from %s just arrived!' % response.url)
        scripts = response.selector.xpath("normalize-space(//title)")
        for scripts in scripts:
            body = response.xpath('//p').extract()
            body2 = "".join(body)
            print remove_tags(body2).encode('utf-8')  


execute(['scrapy','crawl','goal3'])
```

What the code seems to be doing though is taking it's start point as the link for Premier League data, but then crawling all links contained within, even if that link goes to a part of the site that is not related Premier League data. In effect it ends up crawling the whole site, just not from the homepage.

Is there anyway to make Scrapy only scrape dependent links from your starting point?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure `rules` so that links are extracted only for [specific tournament](http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2):

```
rules = [
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('Regions/252/Tournaments/2', )), 
         callback='parse_item', 
         follow=True)
]
```

Comment: @alexce what should my allowed_domains and start_urls be in this example? thanks

Comment: this now returns hardly any crawled pages...like maybe ten or so when before there were thousands. there should still at the very least be hundreds of links returned i would have thought.

Comment: @user3045351 ok, this is how it should work I think, it starts from the link you specified and follows only the links in the tournament. What is your desired result?

Comment: yes you are correct. start at the top level page for the premier league, then scrape all subsequent pages so i get things like the individual pages for players, teams etc...whatever else is in there...before it was crawling tens of thousands of pages, where has now it is crawling 10-20 pages

Comment: @user3045351 well, you can start with the main page: `start_urls = ['whoscored.com']`. In this case, everything about the tournament would be grabbed. Let me know if it helps or not. Thanks.

Comment: hi again. ive already tried that unfortunately. i've posted another question here: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845923/sgmllinkextractor-allow-definition-not-working-with-scrapy' showing what is being printed out into command shell. the output seems to be the same no matter what i put the start_urls =  as. thanks.

Comment: @user3045351 the issue you've created is a completely different one. I think this issue is resolved since it follows only tournament-specific links. Consider accepting the answer if you think it deserves. Thanks.